# Get and set wrapper width based on its content

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I have the following setup:

```html
<div id="wrapper">
    <div class="column1"></div>
    <div class="column3"></div>
    <div class="column2"></div>
</div>
```

```css
#wrapper {
    position:absolute;
}
```

Every "column" has a different width and a `float: left`. So the 3 columns together are, let's say, 900 pixels wide; but I want the wrapper to get it automatically if I put a new column.

So I want to get and set the wrapper's width based on the columns it contains using JavaScript.

Comment: I tried using the white-space:nowrap property on the columns to put it to the 100% of the wrapper content, but it doesn´t work on mozilla, it works on chrome though

Comment: I want to find a javascript solution, cause the css one didn´t work, and I have done a lot of research about and found nothing

Comment: Show us your whole CSS code, including the parts for the columns

Comment: Javascript is really not necessary here. Check out @Bergi's answer below. My guess is that your floats are dropping because the the positioned element doesn't have a width, so it attempts to take no more than 100% of the window width. Instead, change over to `display: inline-block;` (removing the float) and either remove all white space from between the elements, or set `white-space: nowrap;`. With this CSS modification, you should have no issues with the wrapper expanding automatically. See [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/thirdender/Bgp4X/1/).

Comment: that´s exactly what I was trying to do! thanks thirdender!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
var w = 0;
$('#wrapper > div').each(function(index) {
  w += $(this).outerWidth();
});
$('#wrapper').width(w);
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$("#wrapper").width(function() {
    var width = 0;
    $(this).children('[class^="column"]').each(function() {
        width += $(this).width();
    });
    return width;
});​
```

Comment: but what happens if there are different class of columns? like the example I gave, it´s not only the width of one type of column

Comment: This will take the combined width of all elements with a class that starts with `column` and set that width to the `#wrapper` element, is that not what you asked for ?

Comment: It sure did, as the answer you accepted is just about the exact same thing, only written a little differently!

Answer (score 1):

Don't use floats, but `display:inline-block` ([Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Bgp4X/))

Comment: +1 for `display: inline-block;`. Just don't forget to set a vertical-alignment if you want them all top aligned. `white-space: nowrap;` will also work well here if there are any issues keeping them next to each other, or you can just remove the white space between the elements.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/BramVanroy/sYMLr/

```
var totalWidth = 0;
$("div#wrapper > div").each(function(index) {
    totalWidth += parseInt($(this).outerWidth(true), 10);
});

$("div#wrapper").width(totalWidth);​
```